# Access token for the list of effective user in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I have a list of all users in a sheet, I want to get the access token of that particular user from `AdminDirectory` & how many web applications that user holds. How do I achieve that using Google Apps Script?

This code will bring only current user's token. How can I loop through to get a list of tokens?

```js
var accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to run the code with your credentials, you need to use a Google service account to be able to get other users' tokens. 
From this guide [1] where they use Oauth2 library [2], you have an example to get the access token of a single user:

```
var JSON = {
    "private_key": "Your Private Key",
    "client_email": "serviceacount@project-ctrlq.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "1234567890",
    "user_email": "amit@labnol.org"
};

function getOAuthService(user) {
    return OAuth2.createService("Service Account")
        .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
        .setPrivateKey(JSON.private_key)
        .setIssuer(JSON.client_email)
        .setSubject(JSON.user_email)
        .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
        .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
        .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
}

function getUserToken() {
    var service = getOAuthService();
    return service.getAccessToken();
}
```

In the example above, running `getUserToken()` would retrieve you `amit@labnol.org` access token.

[1] https://ctrlq.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script

[2] https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2

Comment: Thanks Andres.Also,Can we get the list of web apps using the token or particular user from AdminDirectory

Comment: You mean Apps Scripts Web Apps? May be the Apps Script REST endpoint can help you. Although there's no specific way to retrieve only the user's list of Web Apps https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes

Comment: Thanks. When i ran the above code ,I get the error "Property Store is required file utilities Google apps script" Do you know what this error is? I could not get much help from google.

Comment: var service = getOAuthService();

Comment: May be replace "getScriptProperties" function for "getUserProperties", because that's what I see in the git hub examples. Other than that I have no idea, the git hub documentation is very complete though.